# Bootstrap jQuery Validate twitter tooltip and removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I done some modifications to create tooltip error messages to fields while validating.
Anyway, Adding Error Class to fields is ok, tooltips are also ok, but when field is valid removeClass doesnt work.

After pressed validate button: its ok
http://imageshack.com/a/img841/9012/iljb.png

But after filling first field, and pressing VALIDATE button, tooltip disappear and this is ok, but class isnt removed (this red box shadow :)
http://imageshack.com/a/img842/5484/ru2i.png

My script i DONT WANT TO EDIT:

```
<script>
    $("#triggerForm").validate({
        debug: false,
        rules: {
            login: {required: true},
            password: {required: true, minlength: 5}
        },
        messages: {
            login: "To pole nie może być puste.",
            password: "To pole nie może być puste."
        }

    });


</script>
```

Here is my code that i want to correct:

```
(function($) {
$.extend(true,$.validator, {
    prototype:{
        defaultShowErrors: function() {
            var self=this;
            $.each( this.successList, function(index, value) {
                $(value.element).removeClass("error").addClass("success");
                $(value).tooltip('destroy');
            });
            $.each( this.errorList, function(index, value) {
                $(value.element).removeClass("success").addClass("error");
                $(value.element).tooltip('destroy').tooltip(self.apply_tooltip_options(value.element,value.message)).tooltip('show');
            });
        },
        apply_tooltip_options: function(element, message){
            var options={
                /* Using Twitter Bootstrap Defaults if no settings are given */
                animation: $(element).data('animation')||true,
                html: $(element).data('html')||false,
                placement: $(element).data('placement')||'top',
                selector: $(element).data('animation')||true,
                title: $(element).attr('title')||message,
                trigger: $.trim('manual '+($(element).data('trigger')||'')),
                delay: $(element).data('delay')||0,
                container: $(element).data('container')||false
            };
            if(this.settings.tooltip_options&&this.settings.tooltip_options[element.name]){
                $.extend(options,this.settings.tooltip_options[element.name]);
            }
            return options;
        }
    }
});}(jQuery));
```

AND CSS:

```
.error {
    border-color: #a94442;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #F00;
}
.error:focus {
    border-color: #843534;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #ce8483;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #F00;
}
.success {
    border-color: #28a900;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #0F0;
}
.success:focus {
    border-color: #28a900;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .075), 0 0 6px #21ce01;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px #0F0;
}
```

Comment: Did you check  this.successList and this.errorList? perhaps de control is still on this.errorList.

Comment: i dont think that it is on errorList because tooltip disappear as it should, but only class isn't removed. What i added to this script is: $(value.element).removeClass("error").addClass("success"); and $(value.element).removeClass("success").addClass("error"); - but only removeClass doesnt work :)

Comment: ¿Why you use  value.element or value only? Can you post here the value of Value.element and value (if its a object). Try with   $(value).removeClass("error").addClass("success");

Comment: yep, it worked :) - $(value).removeClass("error").addClass("success"); but second must be $(value.element).removeClass("success").addClass("error"); :) thxx